# Xquery, checking for sequence membership

Tags: xquery, sequence

```
let $s := ('foo', 'bar')

for $d in collection('mycollection')
where ($d/Id/text() in $s)
return <p>{$d//Name} ({$d//Id})</p>
```

Returns

```
[1.0-ml] XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected In_, expecting Comma_ or Rpar_ or SemiColon_
```

Pointing to:

```
where ($d/Id/text() in $s)
```

What is the correct syntax here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good habit to think of `text()` as equivalent to string.  They're not strings, they're nodes that atomize as strings.  Treating them as the same can lead to subtle, hard to diagnose bugs.  A better formulation is this:

```
let $s := ('foo', 'bar')

for $d in collection('mycollection')
where $d/Id/fn:string() = $s
return <p>{$d/Name} ({$d/Id})</p>
```

That being said, because text() nodes atomize as strings, and elements atomize as the concatenated values of their children, you can usually (when an element has simple text content) simply compare the element to a string (or sequence of strings):

```
let $s := ('foo', 'bar')

for $d in collection('mycollection')
where $d/Id = $s
return <p>{$d/Name} ({$d/Id})</p>
```

Another good practice is to place the selection criteria in the `for` expression where possible, rather than in a `where` clause.  This often makes the intent more clear, but more importantly it can also make it easier for the processor to optimize.  For example

```
let $s := ('foo', 'bar')

for $d in collection('mycollection')[Id = $s]
return <p>{$d/Name} ({$d/Id})</p>
```

This is not only simpler and more expressive, a processor like MarkLogic can convert `collection('mycollection')[Id = $s]` into an efficient `xdml:element-value-query`.  Using the `where` form could result in a brute-force check of every document in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

The `=` operator should be used.

```
let $s := ('foo', 'bar')

for $d in collection('mycollection')
where $d/Id/text() = $s
return <p>{$d/Name} ({$d/Id})</p>
```